# Which method in Arsenic is analogous to Selenuim's back method?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm using [Arsenic](https://github.com/HENNGE/arsenic) instead of Selenium.

Which method in Arsenic is analogous to Selenuim's `back` method?

For example, given this Selenium code that uses `back`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path="chromdriver.exe"))

driver.get("some_url")
driver.find("xpath", "//a[@class='some_xpath_text']")
driver.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.back()
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

How would I convert this to the equivalent Arsenic code? I cannot find an analogous method to `back` in Arsenic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Arsenic function. It seems to be a frozen project that is no accepting merge requests anymore. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/HENNGE/arsenic/pull/142) about it.

Depending on your needs, an alternative may be the library [caqui](https://pypi.org/project/caqui/). It is an asynchronous library to perform actions in WebDrivers too. I've been developing it for personal projects and already tested with my crawlers to get data from more than 2k links.